# Running Postman collection in Jenkins gives me "'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: rest, jenkins, postman

When running my Postman collection in Jenkins, i get error message `'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I saved my postman collections locally and given the path, but it's not working. I tried saving the json link and that too isn't working. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Newman is not installed on the machine that is running Jenkins.

If not already installed, you need to download npm first and install it. You can download it here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

You can do so by running `npm install -g newman` in your CLI.

Comment: I have installed a NodeJs plugin in Jenkins and already had installed Newman locally through CLI. My version is 5.3.2. But somehow, i stiil can't get to Jenkins to run my postman collections. I now get the following error mesage:

FATAL: No installation null found. Please define one in manager Jenkins.
java.io.IOException: No installation null found. Please define one in manager Jenkins.
 at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.NodeJSBuildWrapper.setUp(NodeJSBuildWrapper.java:148)
 at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper.setUp(SimpleBuildWrapper.java:294)